# How to distribute Magento application across several nodes in cluster setup?

Tags: magento-1.9, nginx, redis, loadbalancing, php-fpm

I've been Googling around, but still don't have a clear picture of the subject. 
I've set up following

```
1x LB node (nginx)
1x Webserver node (Nginx + PHP-FPM)
1x Cache-Session node (2 Redis instances)
1x MySQL node
```

So far this set is working well.

Now I need to add one (or two) Webserver nodes (scale horizontally).

I've set up one more node Webserver2 (nginx + PHP-FPM) and mounted Media from Webserver1 as NFS.

The question is how to distribute Magento's application files and folders (e.g. app, downloader, includes, js etc)?

I've been reading about rsync, NFS, csync2, lsyncd but still not sure which one is more appropriate.

As well as how to handle /app/etc/local.xml file and log files.

I'd appreciate any help and advice since I got stuck at this stage.

Thanks

Comment: Magento1.9 does need images physically on the server to render on frontend, you need to implement either some custom logic to change this behvior or sync image files throughout your servers fleet

Answer (score 1):

To start your 1x Webserver is not a cluster, you will require 2x web server to start.

You can use NFS but at a certain volume you could see a performance hit depending on your network. I would recommend using LSYNC or at a minimum RSYNC to keep your instances sync'd.

Your single SQL server will handle volume to a certain level depending on its power. For example we have a Dual Hex core MySQL server with 128GB Memory and it was able to handle 1000 transactions an hour in the cart. With full page cache you should not have to look at a second MySQL server until you go well above this bench mark. However if you want to look at a cluster for MySQL then you should pick Master/Master and consider a frontend cluster server using Percona.

For your Webservers you can sync your data via LSYNC or RSYNC (with CRON). If you use a CDN then you will not have to sync your media folder (Which is the most dynamic section. You should save your Sessions and Cache data to REDIS